# xna method does not accept null

Tags: c#, xna

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace WindowsGame3
{
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    Texture2D ship, bullet, alien;

    Texture2D[] aliens = new Texture2D[20];
    Texture2D[] bullets = new Texture2D[10];

    Vector2 shipPos = new Vector2(200, 540);
    Vector2 alienPos = new Vector2(200, 400);
    Vector2 bulletPos = new Vector2(200, 450);

    Vector2[] aliensPos = new Vector2[20];
    Vector2[] bulletsPos = new Vector2[10];

    int alienCount = 0;
    int bulletCount = 0;

    KeyboardState state = Keyboard.GetState();

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 400;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 600;
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        alien = Content.Load<Texture2D>("alien");
        ship = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ship");

        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
            {
                aliens[alienCount] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("alien");
                aliensPos[alienCount].X = 100 + (x * 40);
                aliensPos[alienCount].Y = 20 + (y * 40);
                alienCount++;
            }  
        }
    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {

    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) && shipPos.X < 360)
        {
            shipPos.X += 5;
        }

        if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) && shipPos.X > 0)
        {
            shipPos.X -= 5;
        }

        if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
        {
                bullets[bulletCount] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("bullet");
                bulletsPos[bulletCount].X = shipPos.X;
                bulletsPos[bulletCount].Y = shipPos.Y;
                bulletCount++;
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);

        spriteBatch.Draw(ship, shipPos, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(alien, alienPos, Color.White);

        for (int alienCount = 0; alienCount < 20; alienCount++)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(aliens[alienCount], aliensPos[alienCount], Color.White);
        }

        for (int bulletCount = 0; bulletCount < 10; bulletCount++)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(bullets[bulletCount], bulletsPos[bulletCount], Color.White);
        }

        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
}
```

I want to create a bullet at the ships position and store that bullet in an array, but in my draw method when i draw the bullet from the array i get the error message    This method does not accept null for this parameter.
Parameter name: texture

Comment: You are passing in a parameter that is null. This is never allowed.

Comment: Look... There's... So many things wrong in that code, I just dunno where to begin. I can only hope it's an edited snippet of code.

Comment: I can see that you're pretty new to XNA and programming. While the allure of being able to make your own video game is pretty exciting I seriously recommend that you do some basic tutorials on C# and learning some programming principles before you tackle something like this or you're going to be hitting your head against the wall for weeks.

Answer (score 3):

In XNA it is good to load all resources before you need them, that is what you have LoadContent() method for. You should load bullet texture in there, and then use it in Update() when necessary.

You only need one Texture2D object per image, even if you want do draw it many times.
You do not need Texture2D array full of exacly the same images.

So, for your example:

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

    alien = Content.Load<Texture2D>("alien"); //only one texture needed
    ship = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ship");
    bullet = Content.Load<Texture2D>("bullet"); //only one texture needed

    //set initial positions as before
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
        {
            aliensPos[alienCount].X = 100 + (x * 40);
            aliensPos[alienCount].Y = 20 + (y * 40);
            alienCount++;
        }  
    }
}
```

when you want to make new alien or bullet, you just set their position, as image is already loaded:

```
if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
{
        bulletsPos[bulletCount].X = shipPos.X;
        bulletsPos[bulletCount].Y = shipPos.Y;
        bulletCount++;
}
```

then, when you have all textures loaded and ready, you can draw it:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

    spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);

    spriteBatch.Draw(ship, shipPos, Color.White);

    for (int alienCount = 0; alienCount < 20; alienCount++)
    {
        //draw alien texture for every aliensPos
        spriteBatch.Draw(alien, aliensPos[alienCount], Color.White);
    }

    for (int bulletCount = 0; bulletCount < 10; bulletCount++)
    {
        //draw bullet texture for every bulletsPos
        spriteBatch.Draw(bullet, bulletsPos[bulletCount], Color.White);
    }

    spriteBatch.End();
    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

And finally to make your ship move, you should read keyboard every frame. You only call Keyboard.GetState() once. when you read it, it returns keys currently pressed, so you need to refresh it every frame.

you should add this to the very begining of your Update() method:

```
state = Keyboard.GetState();
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're trying to draw the bullets before you've made them.  The solution is to simply not draw bullets before you make them.

there are any number of ways to do this, but here's the quickest and dirtiest way:

change

```
    for (int bulletCount = 0; bulletCount < 10; bulletCount++)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(bullets[bulletCount], bulletsPos[bulletCount], Color.White);
    }
```

to

```
    for (int bulletCount = 0; bulletCount < 10; bulletCount++)
    {
        if(bullets[bulletCount] != null)
            spriteBatch.Draw(bullets[bulletCount], bulletsPos[bulletCount], Color.White);
    }
```

Comment: I'm teaching myself so of course its not going to be perfect. But feel free to give me tips on what i could be doing better